# if a row satisfies a condition drop it, else don't drop it

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
import pandas as pd; import numpy as np;
df = {'id': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
   'created_at': ['2020-02-01', '2020-02-02', '2020-02-02', '2020-02-02', '2020-02-03','2020-02-02'],
   'type': ['red', np.nan, np.nan, 'blue', 'yellow', np.nan]}

df = pd.DataFrame (df, columns = ['id', 'created_at','type'])
```

If created_at=2020-02-01 and id=2 or 6 drop row else don't drop. I want to obtain this output;

| id | created_at | type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-02-01 | red |
| 3 | 2020-02-01 | NaN |
| 4 | 2020-02-01 | blue |
| 5 | 2020-02-03 | yellow |

i.e. I don't want to drop all rows with nan value.

Comment: if df['created_at'] == '2020-02-01' and df['id']== 2 or df['id'] == 6:

Answer (score 1):

You would need to use [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
# is the date 2020-02-01?
m1 = df['created_at'].eq('2020-02-01')
# is the id 2 or 6?
m2 = df['id'].isin([2, 6])

# keep if NOT both conditions are matched
out = df[~(m1&m2)]
```

Alternatively:

```
# is the date NOT 2020-02-01?
m1 = df['created_at'].ne('2020-02-01')
# is the id NOT 2 or 6?
m2 = ~df['id'].isin([2, 6])

# keep if either condition is matched
out = df[m1|m2]
```

Comment: df[~(m1&m2)] - its get the common part?
out = df[m1|m2]

Comment: how those logic filtering subsets of variables?

Comment: @PiotrŻak I don't understand your question, do you mean how boolean indexing works? I added a link

Comment: yes, i met this concept first time, and want go a bit further for understanding that type of data operations.